# Tag merge request: OS-X related tags on SO

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

I know this is a duplicate as these tags have been [merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/please-could-we-combine-the-osx-and-macosx-tags) [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39575/merge-tags-macosx-and-mac-os-x-on-so) (and a 3rd time in an answer to one of those questions). Those questions are marked with `[status-completed]` and I need some confirmation/feedback on the current state (see below), so I'm putting this in its own question.

Here are the OS-X tags in question:

```
Tag             Questions           Completed
---------------------------------------------
[osx]                2162        (Target tag)
[os-x]                  3          Mar 5/2010
[os] AND [x]            4          Mar 5/2010
[macosx]              599                      <-- HALP
[macosxserver]          1          Mar 5/2010
[mac-osx]               0                  --
[mac-os-x]              2          Mar 5/2010
[mac-os]                0                  --
```

Here are the set of specific version tags (Leopard, and Snow Leopard):

```
Tag             Questions           Completed
---------------------------------------------
[snow-leopard]        278        (Target tag)
[osx-snow-leopard]     28          Mar 7/2010
[osx-leopard]           1          Mar 5/2010
[osx] AND [leopard]    43    (Target tag set)
[snow] AND [leopard]   10          Mar 7/2010
[snow]                 18          Mar 7/2010
```

There are also 520 questions tagged with `[mac]` AND `[osx]`. I'm inclined to say leave them alone, but I'd like some feedback on that. Should all the questions with the above tags also have `[mac]` on them?

Comment: Bill, I hope I'm not bugging you with all the flagging. ;)

Comment: I took care of the stuff that you flagged.  I know zero about Mac, OS-X, and Snow Leopard, so I'll have to come back later and see what the consensus is on what the proper tags should be.  Thanks for helping us clean this stuff up.

Comment: Not a bother at all.

Comment: @Bill: No problem. I enjoy organizing. It would be nice to not see the captcha every 2nd edit, but oh well. :D

Answer (score 3):

My vote is for [mac](/questions/tagged/mac), [osx](/questions/tagged/osx), and [snow-leopard](/questions/tagged/snow-leopard). Snow Leopard !== OS X. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X#Versions

Makes sense to me to include the platform, if you're going to be deliberate about it, and, as stated, OSX and Snow Leopard are not interchangeable.

Comment: +1 CRAP -- I shouldn't have touched that `[osx-leopard]`-tagged question. We should deal with those ones separately from `[osx]`-related tags. Updated the question to reflect that.