# [macosx] should be [mac-os-x]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

This is a pretty silly issue really, so I'm not going to go as far as posting a retag request for it. I would like to at least gather some thoughts on the subject, though.

I had always thought that words in tag names should be separated by hyphens, but this isn't always correctly followed. I'm a bit anal about things like this when naming things I actually own so that's why this particular instance bugged me a little.  The tag in question is `[macosx]`.  Apple refer to their product as ["Mac OS X"](http://www.apple.com/macosx/), so doesn't it make sense that the tag should be `[mac-os-x]`?

Am I misunderstanding the naming scheme of tags on SO, or is it just that people really aren't that bothered?  Currently there are 997 questions for `[macosx]` on Stack Overflow and only 1 `[mac-os-x]` because I just retagged a post with it.  Super User has separate `[mac]` and `[osx]` (not `[os-x]`) tags, which confuses me further because you're allowed a maximum of 5 tags per question so this would take up 2 of those 5.  I realize this question is more-or-less a dupe of that, with the exception that I'm really trying to find out if this bothers anyone or not.

It looks like `[macosx]` was merged into `[osx]` on Super User, so maybe this is the correct course of action.  However, [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/tags-foobar-versus-foo-bar/2819#2819) on another question states that search terms on the broader internet are the most important factor with tag names, and he even renamed a bunch of tags on super user that didn't correctly include hyphens. With that in mind, I checked the search stats:

http://www.google.com/trends?q=mac+os+x,+mac+osx+&ctab=0  [mac os x] is the winner by a long shot.
http://www.google.com/trends?q=os+x,+osx+&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0 [os x] is the winner.

There's also a retag request [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39575/merge-tags-macosx-and-mac-os-x-on-so) which suggests merging `[macosx]` into `[mac-os-x]`, but it looks like this might have gone the other way because there aren't any `[mac-os-x]` questions anymore.

End of nitpick, I apologise profusely to all who felt compelled to read through that :-)

Comment: I agree with you, but I think this is due to historical precedent. There are statictics at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/please-could-we-combine-the-osx-and-macosx-tags, "Please could we combine the ‘osx’ and ‘macosx’ tags?".

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: yeah. It's those statistics vs Google Trend's statistics. The difference is that a lot of users will use the auto complete tag drop down to choose a tag already in use. You could use the same argument for the Google search terms, except that Google's autocomplete was opt-in until about a year ago.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41365/tag-merge-request-os-x-related-tags-on-so

Comment: Never have liked the mushedtogetherspelling.

Comment: FWIW on Super User, mac is supposed to refer to hardware. osx to Mac OS X itself.

Comment: I don't like using hyphens for spaces here.  I understand its necessity, and prefer it to underscores, but if it's reasonable and understandable to mush words together I'd rather do it.  Also, I write MacOSX normally anyway.

Comment: @David: I can understand that, but I don't think it looks as "good" when you can't write it with camel casing - "macosx".  It also raises the issue of distinguishing the individual words, e.g. expertsexchange vs experts-exchange.